# How to Open JAR Files in Windows 7

Tags: java, file, windows-7, jar, executable

I have looked this up on Google and nothing seems to suit my needs. I am using a Windows 7 computer. I have tried to re-install Java 7 and both the JRE and the JDK downloads say that I already have it on my computer.

I currently have these Java folders:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\
- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\
- C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\

My questions:

1. Which folders are obsolete and can be deleted?
2. How do I make it so that when I double-click on a .JAR executable file, it will properly open without me having to use a command to open it. When I try to open a JAR file currently, it opens a CMD screen and then closes right after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the .jar extension is associated with. Try running the same command from a command prompt window. Hopefully then you can see what the error is and fix it.

Uninstalling all java environments and then reinstalling just what you need will probably work. After uninstalling also delete the java*.exe files from c:\windows\system32. You should not need the JAVA_HOME environment variable to be set, but some batch files require it to be set.

If you want Java to work in your browser you must install a 32-bit JRE.

If you need to run a java program that uses a huge amount of memory (2GB+) or must call a 64 bit DLL directly using JNI or JNA then you must install a 64 bit JRE. If you do java development then you should install a a JDK instead of the JRE. Your IDE may also require that you install a 64 bit JDK instead of a 32 bit JDK.

Comment: So you recommend that I uninstall everything and then JUST install JDK 7?

Comment: Yes, having older JREs can make your system more vulnerable.

Comment: Is there a way to remove all current file associations with JAR's so that when I install JDK7 it will automatically create the file association?

Comment: Looks like you can only change it in Control Panel, not remove it. Go here to see it. Go to Control Panel, search for "associate", click Change the file type associated with a file extension. You can probably remove it in the registry.

Comment: I thank you for your help, but how do I remove it in the registry?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If all the Java folders mentioned above by you are having the specified Jdk folder,
       then its better go for `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05`

**2.** Now copy `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin` into you `System PATH`.

**3.** Type `java -version` on your command prompt, if it returns the **Installed version of JAVA** on your system, then you have properly configured the Java path.

**4.** Now if your `JAR` file is a **command line program**, then you **need to open it from Command Prompt**

**5.** But if you have **GUI program inside the JAR file, then you can use the below to create a JAR file in Eclipse**, and then you can **Double-Click on it to execute it.**

```
File -> Export-> Java ->Runnbale JAR file

Launch configuration : your Class containing the public static void main(String[] args)

Export destination : Target place

Library Handling:

Package required libraries into generated JAR

FINISH
```

Comment: It should not be necessary to put JAVA_HOME\bin on your system path. The file c:\windows\system32\java.exe is already accessible on the path.

Comment: I already have an executable jar file with a GUI and I have correctly set java 7 to my system PATH. How do I open the jar by double-clicking on it **rather** than using a command?

Comment: If you have everything installed, and you can see the version of your java when you type "java -version" on your command prompt, then i think you can execute the jar using the Double click, I hope you have properly mentioned the `class which contains the main() method in the Manifest file`.. I will recommend you to use Eclipse to do it in a easy way, as i mentioned above

Comment: I have the correct class in my manifest file. Do I need to do Open-With? If so, which process? I have tried them all ...

Comment: You dont need to do anything other than Double-Click, if its properly done.......... I have create my Exe Jar in Eclipse, and it runs without any pain

Answer (score 2):

- Please check your JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH settings in your system's
  environment variables
- set your JAVA_HOME or CLASSPATH variables accordingly

  If you want to open up a jar file and see its contents, you can use
  the option "open with" in windows and open that with winzip
- If you want to execute your jar file while clicking it, then you must
  have a main-method in your jar file and configure the same in your
  mainfest file. you should have an **Main-Class** attribute (sample entry in
  mainfest file below)

  Main-Class: com.example.MainClass

  Class-Path: lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar